# Need help creating an excel formula that will number my rows based on the number of records per clientID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to create an excel formula that will number my rows based on the number of times a clientID shows up.

Example: 
column A (clientID) shows something like this

```
111
111
111
222
333
333
```

So I want a formula to put in column B (excel formula) so that it will appear like this:

```
1
2
3
1
1
2
```

(since 111 shows up 3 times, 222 shows up only once, and 333 shows up twice)

together the final result would be:

```
A    B
111  1
111  2
111  3
222  1
333  1
333  2
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe something like,

```
=countif(a$1:a1, a1)
```

Comment: it works :D sorry for the duplicate question!!!